# How to best support the reduced moderation team

Tags: discussion

given the current disruption to the moderation team, how can users best support the volunteers in their site activity. My guesses are:

1. be less vigilant - the working members of the team are likely to be overloaded, so only the worse abuses should be flagged. Let minor issues slide.
2. be more vigilant - the working members of the team are likely to be overloaded,m so are less likely to find problems themselves, so having them brought to their attention more quickly is helpful.
3. carry on as normal - the working members of the team are coping
4. be more proactive - make use of the community tools to edit borderline issues to make them more acceptable, without changing the meaning of the post.

Comment: should I pull those out into separate answers?

Comment: Please don't do #1. I don't have an excess of flags on my plate yet, so don't worry about me being overworked. That said, as Machavity answered, handling review queues does help!

Comment: What about #5 - raise bloody hell and make the man regret some things?

Comment: feel free to add that as an answer @rackandboneman, however I don't see how that assits in the smooth operation of this stack.

Comment: @rackandboneman Protesting the site's staff by adding burden to the community they're supposed to serve seems counterproductive to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right answer is the 3rd or 4th one. The idea behind Stack Exchange is for the communities to be self-governing, self-governing is how things should go.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to help moderators is [review queues](https://space.stackexchange.com/review). That leaves the mods to focus on the moderator-only queues. And by all means, continue to flag.

That was the standing advice when [Workplace.SE had no active moderators](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/no-more-active-moderators-how-should-we-keep-the-site-in-order)